# WPF Application freezes on Windows 10 with no display monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-10

I have a problem with WPF applications built with MS VS2013 and VS2015 on windows 10. When I turn off the display monitor (connected to computer by HDMI), the application layout freezes but the process continue working fine. When I turn on the display monitor back again, the application layout comes back rendering. It's possible to me see this problem through a TeamViewer session.

Additionally, when I runs the WPF application with display monitor turned off, only the layout hangs with a white screen (the application process keeps working)

I have already create a very simple WPF application (with only one button) and happens the same problem.

My computer have only a Intel HD integrated graphics.

Is it a general problem with the current build of windows 10? Is there any solution to the issue or should I wait for a windows update?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: • Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: how do you detect that your app freezes when you turn off the monitor?

Comment: with a TeamViewer session on another pc

Comment: does this happen to other WPF Applications as well? Maybe it is an optimization by WPF to stop updating the picture if display is off